# What is the difference betwen mysql and mysql-community?

Tags: mysql, configuration, gentoo

In Gentoo, what is the difference between `mysql`, `mysql-community`, and `mysql` compiled with `--enable-community-features`?

Comment: What do the docs and/or MySQL web site say about it?

Comment: @John Gardeniers: I couldn't find anything relevant. Hence asking the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This split just reflects MySQL's confusing naming. Check out their [change history for 5.0](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/news-5-0-x.html) to see what happened.

The latest versions are all in "mysql" so unless you need a previous version, you'll just want to emerge mysql with the "community" flag.

Comment: Cheers. Any ideas on what the `community` flag enables?